# Google AppEngine JSONArrayProvider$App, could not be instantiated

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, jackson

I am running a Java REST web service Google AppEngine.  It runs great on my local Google Plugin for Eclipse development server.  However, after it is deployed to the AppEngine Cloud, I get the following error that repeatedly is logged every 4 milliseconds:

```
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
```

This is the same issue as:

[Jersey error on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130328/jersey-error-on-google-app-engine)

However, the solution arrived at there is not working for me.  The solution was "adding the jackson*.jar libs the problem is gone."  I did add all the Jackson jars as $ECLIPSE_PROJECT_HOME/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-all-1.9.7.jar , but I still get the error.  I understand the nature of the problem (Jackson isn't being detected as a Provider by Jersey), but I find interesting that this error only occurs once deployed, not in development.

Perhaps I'll try the new 2.0.0 series of Jackson...

Do I need to add anything referring to Jackson to my $ECLIPSE_PROJECT_HOME/war/WEB-INF/web.xml file?  Right now, I have:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseywebapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>org.pathways.openciss.rest.impl</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.classnames</param-name> 
            <param-value>org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider</param-value> 
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jerseywebapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>OpenCISS.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I've tried it with and without the POJOMappingFeature and JacksonJsonProvider params turned on and off, to no avail...

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.  I was using Jackson libraries not bundled with Jersey.  I removed the Jackson libraries and just installed the Jersey archive containing Jackson from:

http://maven.java.net/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.sun.jersey&a=jersey-archive&v=1.12&e=zip

... which is linked off the website:

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html

The Jersey archive (currently v. 1.12) worked great. Once I added all the jars in its `/lib` folder, the errors went away, as the other poster saw.  What I wasn't understanding was that *only* Jersey archives should be used, not a mix of jars from the Jersey and Jackson web sites, since the Jersey archive contains Jackson jars.

Comment: Updated Version(latest before 2.x): http://maven.java.net/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.sun.jersey&a=jersey-archive&v=1.19&e=zip